# Android Broadcast receiver: ignoring for a certain period of time

Tags: android, android-intent, service

One of my background service has registered a broadcast receiver with the intent `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`. Upon receiving this I start another service. However, I wish to receive this intent only once per hour. Whats the good practice:

1. Should I unregister the broadcast receiver in the 1st service after my 2nd service finishes and put some alarms in the 1st service?
2. I just ignore the broadcast intents received for the next hour?
3. Any other strategy?

PS. I need to be battery efficient :)

Comment: How about a `SyncAdapter`? http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can register **ACTION_TICK** that send intents every minute and only start activity when an internal variable reach > 60 for example. But this may not be the most efficient use of battery. You can use **AlarmMannager** too, but I dont know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved it by AlarmService

1) Register your broadcast first.

2) When you received your intent start alarm service with repeating time

3) When alarm start you can either start service or receiver

See below link Alarm Service [Alarm Service](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)